# SVM Algorithm Implementation on Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a dataset from Stanford on Movie Reviews - [Movie Review Dataset](http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/). It has both training data and testing data - all of them are text files in 2 folders - positive and negative.

How do I implement text classification using SVM algorithm on it? (Using a Python Library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org), it's a great machine learning framework. Have a look at [Working With Text Data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) [Classification of text documents using sparse features example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html), [Feature extractions](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction).

There is also NTLK, but it's not very powerful in ur case, check this thread for more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326694/sentiment-analysis-on-large-collection-of-online-conversation-text).